# Want to redirect Https to http in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I just tried every single method, including WordPress plugins and htaccess to redirect HTTPS to http. But nothign worked.

The thing is I Bought a new domain in the beginning of this year and i started using the HTTP version, but last month I got to know that, the domain was used in 2010. And that time it was used with HTTPS and some URL's of that time are still indexed in Google.

You can check on Google typing both type of versions.

http://www.theblackfridaycoupons.com/

and

https://www.theblackfridaycoupons.com/

Any body have solution for this? I only want HTTP version and want https to redirect to http.

Comment: I don't see any HTTPS versions indexed. The invalid certificate should take care of them pretty quick if any remain.

Comment: Why don't you use https? That should clearly be the default for most web services anyway these days. and it would save you the current hassle...

Answer (score 0):

Just force the URL to redirect to HTTP; on your index.php inside the theme folder add the following code:

```
<?php if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on"){
$location =  "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    wp_redirect($location);
exit();  
?>
```

Comment: But he already tried using the "htaccess method" to redirect https to http. I'm having a similar problem in subdomains, but only those with WordPress installations.